# How can I get reports for last 24h in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get all reports made in last 24h, table has CreatedDate column, so I need to check in database that report was created in last 24h. I know I can use getdate() to get current date, but how can I minus 24h from that attrbiute and then compare that date with CretedDate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`DATEADD()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function as follows:

```
... WHERE CreatedDate > DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myDateTimeColumn BETWEEN GetDate() - 1 AND GetDate()
```